# Get div from div list with specific class

Tags: javascript, html

I have `list` of `div` and want get `div` when contain specified class like `state-expanded`. For example I have got two different `divs`:

```
<div class="row-popular state-expanded no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>TEST</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="row-popular state-collapsed no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>OTHER</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

First `div` have state `state-expanded` and second `state-collapsed`. 
I want get value of `span` where class in `div` is `state-expanded`.

This `list` declaration:

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

In example as I write above, It should return value `TEST`. Please only `JavaScript` - not `jquery` etc.

**Any idea how get it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all divs and then check each to see if it includes class [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/644/)

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (divs[i].getAttribute('class').includes('state-expanded')) {
    console.log(divs[i].querySelector('span').innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Edit: also if you want to change text of that last span child you can do it like this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/645/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`document.getElementsByClassName('state-expanded')` with javascript
and if you are using jQuery.

`$('.state-expanded')`

Answer (score 1):

try this - `var neededDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('state-expanded')[0]`
or you can also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like this:

```
var neededDiv = document.querySelector('.state-expanded');
```

or

```
var neededDiv = document.querySelector('.state-expanded span span');
```

if you need to get nested span with 'TEST' code in it.(According to your example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer.

```
var data  = document.getElementsByClassName('state-expanded')[0];
var data1 = data.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;

console.log(data1);
```

Output : `TEST`

What it will done is, First in data variable it will get the 'state-expanded' div in it then in second line we are getting the second span of value(innerHTML) so it will return TEST.

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9p9ygd01

Answer (score 1):

Try with this below code...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $element = $('.state-expanded span span').html();
  alert($element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-popular state-expanded no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>TEST</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="row-popular state-collapsed no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>OTHER</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like:

```
var txt = document.querySelectorAll('div.state-expanded span span')[0].textContent;
```

querySelectorAll will return the span element contained in a span that is contained in a div with the class state-expanded.

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList, but because in your case there is only one  element you can take the first one (i.e.: [0]).

For the text contained inside you may use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent) attribute.

If instead you need to cycle on all the results obtained using querySelectorAll you need to convert NodeList to array and than use the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function like:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.state-expanded span span')).forEach(function(currValue, index) {
   alert(currValue.textContent);
});
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var txt = document.querySelectorAll('div.state-expanded span span')[0].textContent;
  document.body.innerHTML += '<br>Result: ' + txt;

  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.state-expanded span span')).forEach(function(currValue, index) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>Result in forEach loop: index=' + index + ' textContent=' + currValue.textContent;
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="row-popular state-expanded no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>TEST</span>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="row-popular state-collapsed no-sibling-group">
    <span class="cell cell-id-name" style="flex: 1 1 63px;">
       <span>OTHER</span>
    </span>
</div>
```